# how to get value onchange function and pass this value to onClick function after button is clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have table with input types. when user enter the value , it triggers OnChange function, (1) as shown in figure. Runs the below code

```js
$(document).on("change", ".goalsdata", function(e) {
  debugger;
  var type = $(e.target).parent().parent().parent().parent().children().children().first().children()[0].innerHTML;

  console.log("Checked Value:", type);
});
```

When user clicks on 'commit my goals' button type value collected in "onChange" function should be passed to "onClick" function as argument

```js
$(document).on("click", "#goals_update_bt", function(type) {
      debugger;

      var commit_button = type;

      console.log("this", commit_button)
      e.preventDefault();
      var weekYear = getYearWeekFromDatePicker();
      var datauid = $("#emplist").val()
      //var datauid= {{uid_val}}
      console.log("datauid:", datauid)
      console.log(" weekYear: " + weekYear.year);
      var mkrequest = {
        "request": {
          gen: {
            //crm_activity_goals : ["CRM","External","Internal"]
            crm_activity_goals: commit_button
          },
          goals: {
            "monday": {
              "day": "mon"
            },
            "tuesday": {
              "day": "tue"
            },
            "wednesday": {
              "day": "wed"
            },
            "thursday": {
              "day": "thu"
            },
            "friday": {
              "day": "fri"
            },
            "stnd": {
              "day": "stnd"
            }
          },
          week: {
            week_number: weekYear.week,
            year: weekYear.year
          },
          uid: datauid

        }
      };
```

[image: figure]

Can you please help?

Comment: Set a global variable.

Comment: Or add a class to the element they clicked on, and then the `onclick` method can look for the element with that class and get its value.

Comment: But if you just make `type` a global variable, it will do what you want. You should probably use a more unique name than that, though.

Comment: `.parent().parent().parent().parent().children().children()` is a bad practice.

Comment: Setting random global variables is bad.

Comment: I couldnt create a global variable in this application. Is there an alternative? Really appreciate your help

Comment: instead of `parent()`, use `closest()`.. and instead of `child()` `children()`  use `find()`